# How to encode symbols using CGI::escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cgi, encode

I am using `CGI::escape` to encode symbols in a string, before I send the string as the parameters in a request.

It is working as expected with the `'+'` symbol, and `CGI::escape('foo+bar')` returns `"foo%2Bbar"` as expected.

However, I am running into problems with the `'-'` symbol. `CGI::escape("2015-12-30")` returns `"2015-12-30"`. I was hoping for it to return `"2015%2D12%2D30"`.

To add further context, I am making a request to an endpoint. In the specs for that endpoint they specify how they are expecting to receive the parameters. I have the base url and am adding parameters to the base url.

In the specs they require that the Date param `'2015-12-30'` be sent as `"2015%2D12%2D30"`. That is why I need to encode the **-** symbol.

Comment: Do you already have a URL, or are you trying to add values to a URL? If so, CGI isn't the right library to use. URI would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), not CGI:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.com')
uri.query = URI::encode_www_form(
  'a' => '1+1',
  'b' => '/path/to/file',
  'c' => '2015-12-30'

)
uri.to_s 
# => "http://www.example.com?a=1%2B1&b=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile&c=2015-12-30"
```

The `-` is valid and doesn't need to be encoded.

Comment: I added further context as to why I need to encode the `-` symbol.

Comment: Do you think I should gsub the `-` symbol with what they are expecting before I send it over?

Comment: The request to the endpoint unfortunately didn't work. They want the `-` encoded. Maybe there standards are wrong since the `-` is valid?